# Jquery gallery - rotate/swap/cycle/change effect

Tags: jquery, image, rotation, swap

I'm sorry but I have looked everywhere for an effect but because 'rotate' is used to imply an image swap, then this effect is harder to find than it should be.

I basically want 3 images, 1 large and 2 smaller to the right. Every nth second I want the images to rotate so that the larger image(1) moves to the right into the smaller space(2) and one of the smaller images(3) moves to the bigger area(1).  (see image)

This effect must have been done but I just can't find it anywhere. Any help much appreciated.
Thanks
[image]